# Implicit declaration of function abs - gcc-5.1.0

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

Compiling the following code using gcc-5.1.0 produces a warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘abs’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", abs (-1));

  return 0;
}
```

I have compiled the same code with gcc-4.9.2 and it's not producing any warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `abs()` function is declared in `<stdlib.h>` which you've not included.

GCC 4.9.2 didn't complain because the default compilation mode was C89/C90 (`-std=gnu89`) and functions did not need to be declared before being used in C89 as long as they returned an `int`, but the default compilation mode was changed to C11 (`-stdd=gnu11`) in GCC 5.1.0 (see the [release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html)) and in C11 functions must be declared (or defined) before they are used.

Answer (score 3):

Try to include the `<stdlib.h>` in your code. The `abs()` function is defined inside the `<stdlib.h>`